# PySpark spatial join two datafarames

Tags: python, pyspark, geopandas

I have 2 dataFrames. One with point, another with polygons. I want to use pandas_udf to use sjoin functionality with pySpark

```py
import pandas as pd
from random import random
import geopandas gpd
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from shapely.geometry import Polygon


spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()


polys1 = gpd.GeoSeries([Polygon([(0,0),(2,0),(1,1)]), Polygon([(1.5,1.5),(3,1),(3,3),(1,3)])])
zone_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry':polys1, 'zid':[1,2]})

range_num=10000
data=[[x,random()*3, random()*3] for x in range(range_num)]
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, "id:int,lon:float,lat:float")

@F.pandas_udf(returnType=IntegerType())
def geojoin(lon, lat):
   gdf_tmp = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data=[[lon, lat]], geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(lon, lat))
   join_df = gpd.sjoin(gdf_tmp, zone_df, how='left', op='within')
   return join_df['zid'][0]

point_with_zode_df = spark_df.withColumn('zid', geojoin(spark_df.lon, spark_df.lat))
point_with_zone_df.printSchema()
```

```
*root  
 |--id: long (nullable = true)  
 |--lon: double (nullable = true)  
 |--lat: double (nullable = true)  
 |--zid: integer (nulable = true)*
```

but, then i try to show recieved Dataframe, i got error:
*Py4JJavaError: An error occured while colling o2188.showString.

: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:

Aborting TaskSet 220.0 because task 0 (partition 0)
cannot run anywhere due to node and executor blocklist.
Most recent failure:

...

KeyError: 0*

What's wrong in my code?

**----EDIT**
I wrote func for Pandas

```py
def geojoin(row):
    df_tmp = pd.dataFrame(row).T
    gdf_tmp = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data=df_tmp, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df_tmp.lon, df_tmp.lat))
    join_df = gpd.sjoin(gdf_tmp, zone_df, how='left', op='within')
    return join_df['zid'].values[0]

pandas_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'lon', 'lat']) 
pandas_df['zid'] = pandas_df.apply(geojoin, axis=1)
```

and it work, when i rewrote it for pyspark

```py
@F.pandas_udf(returnType=IntegerType())
def geojoin(x,y):
    df_tmp = pd.DataFrame({'id'}:[0,], 'x':[x,], 'y':[y,]})
    gdf_tmp = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data=df_tmp, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df_tmp['x], df_tmp['y]), columns=['id'])
    join_df = gpd.sjoin(gdf_tmp, zone_df, how='left', op='within')
    return join_df['zid'].values[0]

spark_df = spark_df.withColumn('zid', geojoin(spark_df.lon, spark_df.lat))
spark_df.show()
```

and it isn't work. The same error.

Comment: Hi! Can you [please read](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557) about the problems with images of text and then edit your question to add transcriptions of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). I'm referring to the printscreen of your error message :)

Comment: try `return join_df['zid']`

Comment: @leaf_yakitori,  i tried `return join_df['zid']`  too. Did not help

Comment: since your code works in `Panda`, just use `pandas_df = your_df.toPandas()` then use your panda code.

Comment: this testing dataFrame. in prod my dataframe contains some mlln rows

Comment: i think, this's error because the operation is very hard. the solution is in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59143891/spatial-join-between-pyspark-dataframe-and-polygons-geopandas topic